# accessing elements form a multi-layered json response

Tags: reactjs, database, loops

I am trying to show the orders in a database. The structure in the database is as shown below.
I would like to accomplish that I get a table with the orders (number, table and total) in 1 row with actions behind it (like print, complete) and that I can access the individual elements (cola, fanta, etc) in functions to do calculations etc (like run stock checks etc).

```
"orders": {
    "1683890898919": {
      "formJson": {
        "cola": "0",
        "fanta": "1",
        "hamburger": "6",
        "iced tea": "6",
        "opnemer": "Jens",
        "pensen": "5",
        "sprite": "0",
        "status": "OK:1683890898248",
        "table": "16",
        "total": "130"
      }
    },
    "1683890989516": {
      "formJson": {
        "cola": "1",
        "fanta": "1",
        "hamburger": "8",
        "iced tea": "0",
        "opnemer": "Jake",
        "pensen": "0",
        "sprite": "0",
        "status": "OK:1683890898919",
        "table": "19",
        "total": "187.5"
      }
    }
```

The program is build up in different steps to build up the components of the page:

1. function to retrieve the data and to pass it to a function to create a table:

```
export function Orders() {
    const [orders, setOrders] = useState({});
    
    useEffect(() => {
      return onValue(ref(database, '/orders'), querySnapShot => {
      let data = querySnapShot.val() || {};
      let orders = {...data};
      setOrders(orders);
    });
    }, []);
    
  return <FilterableProductTable orders={orders} />;
}
```

2. function to create a product table

```
function FilterableProductTable({ orders }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <OrderTable
        orders={orders}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

3. function to create the orderTable

```
function OrderTable({ orders }) {
  const rows = [];
  var ord = [];
  
  Object.keys(orders).forEach(function(key) {
      ord.push(orders[key]);
  });
  
  ord.map(item => {
        rows.push(
          <OrderRow
            item={item}
            key={item.name}/>
        );
 
})

  return (
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Orders in het systeem:</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

4. function to show an order row

```
function OrderRow({ item }) {
    
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{item}</td>
      <td>{item.total}</td>
      <td>print</td>
    </tr>
  );
}
```

It's at step 3 that it goes wrong, I cannot seem to get deeply enough in the nested structure. i am able to get the "number" of the order (like 1683890898919 in the example above), but I don't seem to be able to access the children.

I tried doing forEach loops, maps, mapping to array ... but can't seem to find a solution.